# How to stop dhcpd?

Tags: server, dhcpd

I am trying to stop the dhcpd ,but whenever I stop it ,it restart again immediately.

```
$ ps aux | grep dhcp
dhcpd     7116  0.0  0.1  19672  6604 ?        Ss    16:33   0:00
dhcpd -user dhcpd -group dhcpd -f -q -4 -pf 
/run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf wlan0
```

I tried

```
/etc/init.d/dhcpd stop
```

but with no luck

```
bash: /etc/init.d/dhcpd: No such file or directory
```

also

```
service dhcpd stop
```

gives me this

```
dhcpd: unrecognized service
```

Comment: Try this: sudo service isc-dhcp-server stop

Comment: This command  returns "stop: Unknown job: isc-dhcp-server"

Comment: Then you'll need to find what is the exact name of the service running dhcp. Type "sudo service " and then press Tab twice, and see if any of the services available has something related to dhcp.

Comment: you can try:
```
kill -9 $(cat /var/run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid)